# Получение кадра из видеопотока

Tags: java, android, видео, потоки-данных, streaming

Нужно получить изображение из видеопотока.
Пробую сделать это таким способом

```
    public static Bitmap getVideoFrame(Context context, Uri uri) {
    MediaMetadataRetriever retriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
    try {
        retriever.setDataSource(uri.toString(),new HashMap<String, String>());
        return retriever.getFrameAtTime();
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } catch (RuntimeException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            retriever.release();
        } catch (RuntimeException ex) {
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Но данный метод не работает для стримов.
Для отображения видео использую библиотеку LibVLC

Answer (score 1):

Данная проблема решается с помощью библиотеки [FFmpegMediaDataRetriever](https://github.com/wseemann/FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever)

```
FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever mmr = new FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever();
mmr.setDataSource(mUri);
mmr.extractMetadata(FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_ALBUM);
mmr.extractMetadata(FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_ARTIST);
Bitmap b = mmr.getFrameAtTime(2000000, FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever.OPTION_CLOSEST); // frame at 2 seconds
byte [] artwork = mmr.getEmbeddedPicture();
mmr.release();
```